# Insert trigger ends up inserting duplicate rows in partitioned table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a partitioned table with (what I think) the appropriate `INSERT` trigger and a few constraints on it. Somehow, `INSERT` statements insert 2 rows for each `INSERT`: one for the parent and one for the appropriate partition.

The setup briefly is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
id SERIAL NOT NULL,
d_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
label VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE foo_0 (CHECK (d_id % 2 = 0)) INHERITS (foo);
CREATE TABLE foo_1 (CHECK (d_id % 2 = 1)) INHERITS (foo);

ALTER TABLE ONLY foo ADD CONSTRAINT foo_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE ONLY foo_0 ADD CONSTRAINT foo_0_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE ONLY foo_1 ADD CONSTRAINT foo_1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);

ALTER TABLE ONLY foo ADD CONSTRAINT foo_d_id_key UNIQUE (d_id, label);
ALTER TABLE ONLY foo_0 ADD CONSTRAINT foo_0_d_id_key UNIQUE (d_id, label);
ALTER TABLE ONLY foo_1 ADD CONSTRAINT foo_1_d_id_key UNIQUE (d_id, label);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo_insert_trigger()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF NEW.id IS NULL THEN
       NEW.id := nextval('foo_id_seq');
    END IF;

    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO foo_' || (NEW.d_id % 2) || ' SELECT $1.*' USING NEW;
    RETURN NEW;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER insert_foo_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT ON foo
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE foo_insert_trigger();
```

Upon further debugging I isolated what's causing it: the fact that the `INSERT` trigger returns `NEW` as opposed to just `NULL`. However I do want my insert statements to return the auto-increment `id` and if I just return `NULL` that won't be the case.

What's the solution? Why does returning `NEW` cause this seemingly "strange" behavior?

**UPDATE #1**

Well, I know why the rows got inserted twice as it is clear from the documentation of triggers:

> Trigger functions invoked by per-statement triggers should always
>   return NULL. Trigger functions invoked by per-row triggers can return
>   a table row (a value of type HeapTuple) to the calling executor, if
>   they choose. A row-level trigger fired before an operation has the
>   following choices:
>
> It can return NULL to skip the operation for the current row. This
>   instructs the executor to not perform the row-level operation that
>   invoked the trigger (the insertion, modification, or deletion of a
>   particular table row).
>
> For row-level INSERT and UPDATE triggers only, the returned row
>   becomes the row that will be inserted or will replace the row being
>   updated. This allows the trigger function to modify the row being
>   inserted or updated.

But my question is still how is it possible to not return `NEW` and still be able to get the auto-incremented `id`, or `ROW_COUNT` for example?

**UPDATE #2**

I found a solution, but I sure hope that there's a better one. Basically, you can add an `AFTER TRIGGER` to delete the row inserted into the parent table. This seems horribly inefficient, so if anyone has a better solution, please post it!

For reference the solution is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_foo_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT ON foo
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE foo_insert_trigger();


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo_delete_master() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM ONLY foo WHERE id = NEW.id;
    RETURN NEW;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_foo_trigger
    AFTER INSERT ON foo
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE foo_delete_master();
```

Comment: It's a real deficiency in PostgreSQL's inheritance based partitioning. One of several; another is that you don't get a correct returned rowcount when inserting into / updating / deleting from a partitioned table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler way is to create stored procedure instead of the triggers, for example add_foo( [parameters] ), which would decide which partition is suitable to insert a row to and return id (or the new record values, including id). For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_foo(
    _d_id   INTEGER
,   _label  VARCHAR(4)
) RETURNS BIGINT AS $$
DECLARE
    _rec    foo%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    _rec.id := nextval('foo_id_seq');
    _rec.d_id := _d_id;
    _rec.label := _label;
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO foo_' || ( _d_id % 2 ) || ' SELECT $1.*' USING _rec;
    RETURN _rec.id;
END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thanks Tomasz. The second solution (the function) is a more efficient way but it suffers from maintenance problems. That is, every time a column changes or added to the table, the function needs to be updated. Btw, I tried out your first solution and it doesn't seem to work, at least for me.

Comment: I added your trigger, with RETURN NULL statement, to make explicit that all these triggers should cooperate. Tested, it works :)

Comment: Tomasz: I tested your solution (the one with the `AFTER` triggers) and it doesn't return the auto-incremented seq id. That was one of my problems. The solution that I posted in UPDATE 2 does return the id.

Comment: I deleted this solution. I am unable now to reproduce the success  that the steps with the additional 'after' triggers allegedly led to.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution to this problem is offered by this question:
[Postgres trigger-based insert redirection without breaking RETURNING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22929675/postgres-trigger-based-insert-redirection-without-breaking-returning)

In summary, create a view for your table and then you can use `INSTEAD OF` to handle the update while still being able to return `NEW`.

Untested code, but you get the idea:

```
CREATE TABLE foo_base (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL,
  d_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  label VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL
);

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW foo AS SELECT * FROM foo_base;

CREATE TABLE foo_0 (CHECK (d_id % 2 = 0)) INHERITS (foo_base);
CREATE TABLE foo_1 (CHECK (d_id % 2 = 1)) INHERITS (foo_base);

ALTER TABLE ONLY foo_base ADD CONSTRAINT foo_base_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE ONLY foo_0 ADD CONSTRAINT foo_0_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE ONLY foo_1 ADD CONSTRAINT foo_1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);

ALTER TABLE ONLY foo_base ADD CONSTRAINT foo_base_d_id_key UNIQUE (d_id, label);
ALTER TABLE ONLY foo_0 ADD CONSTRAINT foo_0_d_id_key UNIQUE (d_id, label);
ALTER TABLE ONLY foo_1 ADD CONSTRAINT foo_1_d_id_key UNIQUE (d_id, label);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo_insert_trigger()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    IF NEW.id IS NULL THEN
       NEW.id := nextval('foo_base_id_seq');
    END IF;

    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO foo_' || (NEW.d_id % 2) || ' SELECT $1.*' USING NEW;
    RETURN NEW;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER insert_foo_trigger
    INSTEAD OF INSERT ON foo
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE foo_insert_trigger();
```

Comment: Thank you James. I'll give this a try as well.