# Postgres trigger-based insert redirection without breaking RETURNING

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using table inheritance in postgres, but the trigger I'm using to partition data into the child tables isn't quite behaving right. For example, this query returns nil, but I would like it to return the `id` of the new record.

```sql
INSERT INTO flags (flaggable_id, flaggable_type) 
VALUES (233, 'Thank') 
RETURNING id;
```

If I change the return value of the trigger function from `NULL` to `NEW`, I get the desired `RETURNING` behavior, but then two identical rows are inserted in the database. This makes sense, since a non-null return value from the trigger function causes the original `INSERT` statement execute, whereas returning NULL causes the statement to halt execution. A unique index might halt the second insertion, but would probably raise an error.

Any ideas how to make the `INSERT` with `RETURNING` work properly with a trigger like this?

```sql
CREATE TABLE flags (
  id integer NOT NULL,
  flaggable_type character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  flaggable_id integer NOT NULL,
  body text
);

ALTER TABLE ONLY flags
    ADD CONSTRAINT flags_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);

CREATE TABLE "comment_flags" (
 CHECK ("flaggable_type" = 'Comment'),
 PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
 FOREIGN KEY ("flaggable_id") REFERENCES "comments"("id")
) INHERITS ("flags");

CREATE TABLE "profile_flags" (
 CHECK ("flaggable_type" = 'Profile'),
 PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
 FOREIGN KEY ("flaggable_id") REFERENCES "profiles"("id")
) INHERITS ("flags");

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION flag_insert_trigger_fun() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $BODY$
BEGIN
  IF (NEW."flaggable_type" = 'Comment') THEN
    INSERT INTO comment_flags VALUES (NEW.*);
  ELSIF (NEW."flaggable_type" = 'Profile') THEN
    INSERT INTO profile_flags VALUES (NEW.*);
  ELSE
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Wrong "flaggable_type"="%", fix flag_insert_trigger_fun() function', NEW."flaggable_type";
  END IF;
  RETURN NULL;
END; $BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER flag_insert_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT ON flags
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE flag_insert_trigger_fun();
```

Comment: It's a known wart with trigger-based partitioning, but unfortunately there isn't tons of work going on in the partitioning support at the moment.

Comment: Updated my answer, maybe interested in that views' columns can have a default value too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only workaround I found, is to create a view for the base table & use `INSTEAD OF` triggers on that view:

```
CREATE TABLE flags_base (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    flaggable_type character varying(255) NOT NULL,
    flaggable_id integer NOT NULL,
    body text
);

ALTER TABLE ONLY flags_base
    ADD CONSTRAINT flags_base_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);

CREATE TABLE "comment_flags" (
 CHECK ("flaggable_type" = 'Comment'),
 PRIMARY KEY ("id")
) INHERITS ("flags_base");

CREATE TABLE "profile_flags" (
 CHECK ("flaggable_type" = 'Profile'),
 PRIMARY KEY ("id")
) INHERITS ("flags_base");

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW flags AS SELECT * FROM flags_base;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION flag_insert_trigger_fun() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $BODY$
BEGIN
  IF (NEW."flaggable_type" = 'Comment') THEN
    INSERT INTO comment_flags VALUES (NEW.*);
  ELSIF (NEW."flaggable_type" = 'Profile') THEN
    INSERT INTO profile_flags VALUES (NEW.*);
  ELSE
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'Wrong "flaggable_type"="%", fix flag_insert_trigger_fun() function', NEW."flaggable_type";
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END; $BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER flag_insert_trigger
  INSTEAD OF INSERT ON flags
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE flag_insert_trigger_fun();
```

But this way you **must** supply the `id` field on each insertion (even if `flags_base`'s primary key has a default value / is a serial), so you must prepare your insert trigger to fix `NEW.id` if it is a `NULL`.

**UPDATE**: It seems views' columns can have a default values too, set with

```
ALTER VIEW [ IF EXISTS ] name ALTER [ COLUMN ] column_name SET DEFAULT expression
```

which is only used in views have an insert/update rule/trigger.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-alterview.html

Answer (score 2):

@pozs provided a correct answer but didn't quite provide the code for a full working implementation. I tried to include the code in an edit on his question, but it was not accepted. He instead suggested yet another approach, which looks cleaner, but may have some drawbacks (in the case where you re-use your trigger function elsewhere).

Including my solution here for reference:

```
CREATE TABLE base_flags (
  id integer NOT NULL,
  flaggable_type character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  flaggable_id integer NOT NULL,
  body text
);

ALTER TABLE ONLY base_flags
  ADD CONSTRAINT base_flags_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);

CREATE SEQUENCE base_flags_id_seq
  START WITH 1
  INCREMENT BY 1
  NO MINVALUE
  NO MAXVALUE
  CACHE 1;

ALTER SEQUENCE base_flags_id_seq OWNED BY base_flags.id;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW flags AS SELECT * FROM base_flags;

CREATE TABLE "comment_flags" (
  CHECK ("flaggable_type" = 'Comment'),
  PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
  FOREIGN KEY ("flaggable_id") REFERENCES "comments"("id")
) INHERITS ("flags");

CREATE TABLE "profile_flags" (
  CHECK ("flaggable_type" = 'Profile'),
  PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
  FOREIGN KEY ("flaggable_id") REFERENCES "profiles"("id")
) INHERITS ("flags");

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION flag_insert_trigger_fun() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $BODY$
  BEGIN
    IF NEW.id IS NULL THEN
      NEW.id := nextval('base_flags_id_seq');
    END IF; 
    IF (NEW."flaggable_type" = 'Comment') THEN
      INSERT INTO comment_flags VALUES (NEW.*);
    ELSIF (NEW."flaggable_type" = 'Profile') THEN
      INSERT INTO profile_flags VALUES (NEW.*);
    ELSE
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Wrong "flaggable_type"="%", fix flag_insert_trigger_fun() function', NEW."flaggable_type";
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
  END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER flag_insert_trigger
  INSTEAD OF INSERT ON base_flags
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE flag_insert_trigger_fun();
```

Comment: I get this error on creating trigger in postgres: Tables cannot have INSTEAD OF triggers.